# How to use Maples dsolve with integral condition

Tags: maple

Suppose I have the  (simplified), differential equation

```
de:=diff(f(x),x,x,x)=1;
```

I do have two boundary conditions, e.g. `f(-1)=0` and `f(1)=0`. However, the third integration constant should obey the integral condition `int(f(x),x=-1..1)=0`.

I know how to deal with the regular boundary conditions, i.e.

```
 ans:=dsolve({de,f(1)=0,f(-1)=0});
```

But, how do I deal with the integral condition?

I tried something like

```
ans:=dsolve({de,f(1)=0,f(-1)=0,int(f(x),x=-1..1)=0});
```

But this does not solve the differential equation:

> Error, (in dsolve) the input system cannot contain equations in the arbitrary parameters alone; found equation: int(f(x),x = -1 .. 1,AllSolutions)

My problem does have a solution with an additional step:

```
solve(int(rhs(ans),x=-1..1)=0);
```

But, I would like to supply this condition right in `dsolve`. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the order by 1. That is, let **F** represent the antiderivative of **f** (integrated from -1) and include it in the call to **dsolve** along with two initial conditions on **F** based on the integral.

```
eval(
     f(x),
     dsolve({
          diff(f(x),x$3)=1, f(-1)=0, f(1)=0,
          diff(F(x),x)=f(x), F(-1)=0, F(1)=0
     })
);
```

Comment: Thanks, in my example I should have put `f'''=1`, but for the answer is does not matter. Anyhow, this solution is not really elegent, as I still need the additional step, right?

Comment: Okay, if you want elegance, I modified my Answer so that no extra step is required, and so that it is closer to the original.